# SELECT INTO @var in Stored Procedure not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have data coming in from an external source that when it comes is comma separated. I am creating a stored procedure that will be called from an already existing before insert trigger. The stored procedure will counts the number of commas in the string, loops that many iterations, grabbing the substring for that index, ie on iteration 2 for string "abc,def,ghi"  returns deg, then creates an entry in a join table IF what is returned is validated against a table of known good values.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `create_isbn_catalog_join_table`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE create_isbn_catalog_join_table(catalog VARCHAR(32),isbn CHAR(20))
BEGIN
SET @x = 1;
-- a crappy way to count substr within a string
SELECT (length(catalog)-length(replace(catalog,',',''))) INTO  @catalog_count;
SET @catalog_count = @catalog_count + 1;
REPEAT
-- a crappy way to simulate php substr
SET @cat = '';
SELECT REPLACE(
          SUBSTRING(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(catalog, ',', @x),
            LENGTH(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(catalog, ',',@x -1)
            ) + 1
          ),
  ',','') INTO @cat;

set @cat1 = 'WX';
set @valid_catalog = 0 ;


IF EXISTS (select 1 from valid_catalogs where catalog = @cat)  THEN

    select count(*),@cat from valid_catalogs where catalog = @cat ;
    select count(*),@cat1 from valid_catalogs where catalog = @cat1 ;

  INSERT INTO iz_products_catalogs
   (`isbn`,`catalog`)
      VALUES
   (isbn,@cat);
END IF;

SET @x = @x + 1 ;

UNTIL @x > @catalog_count END REPEAT;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Whats very odd here is the following i incorrectly am passing the IF clause to determine if the current catalog in the loop is valid or not; exemplified by the 2 querys that are being ran:

```
select count(*),@cat from valid_catalogs where catalog = @cat ;
select count(*),@cat1 from valid_catalogs where catalog = @cat1 ;
```

Note @cat is from the substring select and that @cat1 is set via a SET command. Both are 2 char values that are not in the valid catalog table. The return value is:

```
+----------+------+
| count(*) | @cat |
+----------+------+
|       27 | WZ   |
+----------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+----------+-------+
| count(*) | @cat1 |
+----------+-------+
|        0 | WX    |
+----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Both WZ or WX are not in the valid_catalogs table. But when querying the count of from valid catalogs using @cat, it returns 27 (which is the total number of rows in the table) which should be zero as there is not a 'WZ' row. when querying with @cat1 it accurately returns 0.

Comment: Just a random "drive by" guess, but have you made sure your parameter names don't collide with any names of fields in the tables involved in those queries?

Comment: nope, cat is not field anywhere. also verified that by changing \@cat t \@cat22 which produced same results.

Comment: I meant the stored proc parameters `catalog` and `isbn`; not the session variables (indicated by `@` prefixes). _... from valid_catalogs where catalog ..._ could be using the parameter value rather than the field value; I seem to recall seeing people having similar ambiguity issues previously, but cannot recall offhand if this is the exact issue.

Comment: NAILED IT! .. .thanks!!